# How to get Timestamp of next Thursday in GMT

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat

I am making a Countdown Timer, which will ran on GMT. Resets 12:00 A.M GMT Thursday. Then it will countdown again.

I have already made the Countdown Timer. It accepts 2 inputs.

1 - Current TimeStamp 
2 - TimeStamp of next Thursday ( 12:00 A.M GMT ). Suppose if it is currently  24.7.2014 3:40 AM GMT, then next Thursday should be same day and timestamp shoud be for 24.7.2014 12:00 GMT. 
And so on.

I am having problem with the second part. I am able to get it in my Local timezone ( IST ). I am trying to get it for GMT. But things are getting messed up. I don't know where i am doing it wrong.

Would love to get my concepts cleared from here.

Code is :-

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(GetNextThursday());

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Current TIME DETAILS According to currentTimeMills :");
        long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(endTime);
        Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(endTime);




    }

    public static long GetNextThursday() {
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
           Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

           int todayday=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

           switch(todayday)
           {

           case 1:
               //It's sunday
               c.add(Calendar.DATE, 4);
               c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);
               break;
           case 2:
               //It's Monday
               c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
               c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);
               break;
           case 3:
               //It's Tuesday
               c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
               c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);
               break;
           case 4:
               //It's Wednsday
               c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
               c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);
               break;
           case 5:
               //It's Thursday

               if(c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
               {
                   c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);
               }
               else
               {
                   c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
                   c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);

               }
               break;

           case 6:
               c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
               c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);
               break;

           case 7:
               c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
               c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE), 12, 00, 00);

           }

          System.out.println("Next Thursday Based On CURRECT TIME (Default)");
          System.out.println(c.getTime());
          System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());        

          System.out.println();

          TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
          c.setTimeZone(tz);
          System.out.println(c.getTime());
          System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());


          System.out.println();

          return (c.getTimeInMillis());

    }

}
```

What it is giving is correct. It is giving TimeStamp for next Thursday 12:00 AM. But it is giving it in IST. I want the same in GMT.

Looking forward for possible solutions.

PS: I tried to find the solution on StackOverflow and then i have posted it here. Maybe the solution is available there but i was not able to find 1.

Comment: Well, a `Date` will never be in a particular time zone anyway - but it sounds like you just need to set the `TimeZone` of your `Calendar` to UTC.

Comment: I tried that.  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); But display is still in IST. Any solution ?

Comment: When you say "display is still in IST" I suspect you mean when you call `Date.toString()` - that will always use your local time zone, but that doesn't mean that the value itself is wrong.

Comment: As Jon mentioned date isn't in any timezone. So when you print Date it will print in current time zone. Set the timezone for your formatter and parse the date using it to print in any timezone
: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)